# A vector/tensor field is parallel if and only if its total covariant derivative vanishes

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

I'm trying to solve Problem $4.12$ in John Lee's book *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. It states the following:

> Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold with or without boundary, $\nabla$ is a connection in $TM$, and $A$ is a smooth vector or tensor field on $M$. Then $A$ is parallel if and only if $\nabla A\equiv 0$.

I'm trying to prove this for the vector field case, but I'm having some trouble. Using Lee's notation on Page 98 of the book, for $A\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ we can write the $(1,1)$-tensor field $\nabla A$ as
$$\nabla A= A^i_{;j}E_i\otimes \epsilon^j=\left(E_jA^i+A^k\Gamma^i_{jk}\right)E_i\otimes \epsilon^j$$
by writing $A=A^iE_i$ in some local frame $(E_i)$ and corresponding dual frame $(\epsilon^j)$. Hence if $A$ is parallel, then the covariant derivative $D_tA(t)\equiv 0$ for every smooth curve $\gamma$ on $M$.

**Question:** From my understanding, if $D_tA(t)\equiv 0$ this means that
$$\dot{A}^k(t)+ \dot{\gamma}^i(t)A^j(t)\Gamma^k_{ij}(\gamma(t))=0$$
where $k=1,\ldots, n$. Hence to solve the problem I'd ideally want to have
$$\left(\dot{A}^k(t)+ \dot{\gamma}^i(t)A^j(t)\Gamma^k_{ij}(\gamma(t))\right)E_k=\left(E_jA^i+A^k\Gamma^i_{jk}\right)E_i\otimes \epsilon^j$$
somehow, but the righthand side is written in terms of a local frame and coframe while the lefthand side isn't, so I'm not sure how things cancel out here to yield an equality or bring something illuminating to light.

Any help on this problem is appreciated, sorry for the trouble! I appreciate the help.

Comment: No, the LHS of your equation is certainly not $\nabla A$. What is it?

Comment: @TedShifrin My idea was to show that if $\nabla A\equiv 0$ then $D_tA(t)\equiv 0$ and vice versa. The expression on the LHS is $D_tA(t)$...

Comment: But the expression on the right is not. And the left side is not quite what you say; why? You must write $D_tA(t)$ in the form $\nabla_YA$ and write both sides of your equation correspondingly.

Comment: @TedShifrin after coming back to this problem, I fixed the issue on the LHS. However, I'm not sure how to write the RHS in terms of $\gamma$, and as written in my comment in the current answer below, the current strategy to do this is unclear to me. Could you be a little more explicit with how to get equality on both sides?

Comment: Your edit is not right, as you defined $A=A^iE_i$; also, trivially, you mean $\gamma(t)$, I presume. You still need to evaluate the right-hand side on the tangent vector to the curve,

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, should be fixed. As for evaluating the RHS on the tangent vector to the curve, are you talking about writing out $\nabla A$ with respect to $\dot{\gamma}(t)$? If so, I'm not sure how this would work. My apologies if these questions are trivial, this problem is just confusing me notationally.

Comment: No, I’m saying you need to correctly interpret $E_jA^i$ and evaluate$e^j$ on $\dot\gamma$. You also should aim to have your indices on $E_k$ agree on both sides of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

I know @TedShifrin is trying to guide you through the process, but let me write it out more explicitly.

So your
$\text{LHS}\cdot E_k = D_t A(t),$
and your RHS is $\nabla A$.

If you use $(\nabla A)(\dot \gamma) = D_t A(t)$, and $\dot \gamma = \dot \gamma^\ell E_\ell$, you at least will match these two expressions.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by $(\nabla A)(\dot{\gamma})$? Unless this means $\nabla_{\dot{\gamma}}A$, this doesn't make any sense since $\nabla A$ is a (1,1)-tensor field. Even if it did it's still unclear how this is equal to $D_tA(t)$...

Comment: Yes, it does mean that. Then, it should be clear that $\nabla_{\dot \gamma} A = D_t A(t)$, since $D_t$ is the covariant differentiation along the curve $\gamma$ w.r.t. $t$, hence this is the same as $\nabla_{\dot \gamma} A$. This is even just a definition to me now, so it all depends on how $D_t$ was introduced to you.